# Class hierarchy in Python

Tags: python, class-hierarchy

I have a relaisboard connected to an arduino via firmata protocol using Python bindings. The communication works without problems using pyfirmata (https://github.com/tino/pyFirmata).

The relaisboard has 16 relais. Every group of 3 relais is a channel. Every channel is connected to a Device Under Test input or output. This just to have a rough description of the purpose of the releboard.

Below you can find a skeleton of the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

__version__ = '0.1'

# Fault Injection Unit

# Power is connected to Fault Bus 1
# Ground is connected to Fault Bus 2

from pyfirmata import Arduino

class FaultInsertionBoard(object):

    def __init__ (self, comPort = 'COM3'):
        """Initalize the Fault insertion Board

        Open communication with host via serial port

        Arguments:
        comPort -- The serial port used to connect the board to the host.
        """
        self.board = Arduino(comPort)

    class Channel(object):

        def __init__ (self, aChannel):
            """ Create a Channel"""
            pass

        def NoFault():
            """ Set the channel to the "No fault" condition

            No Fault condition is:
            -- DUT channel connected to the testing sistem
            -- DUT channel disconnected from the Fault bus 1  
            -- DUT channel disconnected from the Fault bus 2
            """
            pass


        def OpenCircuit():
            """ Set the channel to the "Open Circuit fault" condition

            Open Circuit fault condition is:
            -- DUT channel disconnected from the testing sistem
            -- DUT channel disconnected from the Fault bus 1  
            -- DUT channel disconnected from the Fault bus 2
            """
            pass

        def ShortToGround():
            """ Set the channel to the "Short to Ground fault" condition

            Open Circuit fault condition is:
            -- DUT channel disconnected from the testing sistem
            -- DUT channel disconnected from the Fault bus 1  
            -- DUT channel connected to the Fault bus 2
            """
            pass

        def ShortToPower():
            """ Set the channel to the "Short to Ground fault" condition

            Open Circuit fault condition is:
            -- DUT channel disconnected from the testing sistem: channel relay is open
            -- DUT channel connected to the Fault bus 1: Fault Bus 1 relay is closed 
            -- DUT channel disconnected from the Fault bus 2: Fault Bus 1 relay is open
            """
            pass

def main():

    FaultBoard = FaultInsertionBoard('COM3')
    VoutSensor = FaultBoard.Channel(0)  
    IOutSensor = FaultBoard.Channel(1)    
    VoutSensor.NoFault()
    IOutSensor.NoFault()
    VoutSensor.ShortToGround()
    IOutSensor.ShortToPower()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Where:

- `FaultInsertionBoard` is a simple wrapper of the `Arduino` class in
  `Firmata`.
- `Channel(n)` identifies the `n`-th group of three relais
- `NoFault`, `ShortToPower`, `ShortToGround` are various configurations of
  the three relais of each channel (it does not matter the actual
  configuration).

Now the question: I have a very good experience with embedded firmware written in C, far less in Python. Obviously the code above is not correct.

Can someone suggest me a class framework in order to get the above functionality? In other words, how can I write the Python code in order to drive the relais as described above?

PS: alternatively I could write something like this:

```
FaultBoard = FaultInsertionBoard('COM3')
FaultBoard.Channel(0).NoFault()
```

but I think it is less elegant and clear.

Comment: You do not show the code for `FaultInsertionBoard`; how do you expect to get help?

Comment: Does the code that you posted not work or something?

Comment: Sorry, my fault.I thought I put the code. See my edited question above.

Comment: Don't define nested classes. It serves no purpose in Python. If that is just an indentation error, please fix it.

Comment: So you are asking us to implement your classes for you?

Comment: No, I will implement the classes by myself.I was not clear. I would like to know how to create the structure of the class(es) so to be able to write a command as FaultBoard.Channel(0).NoFault().

Comment: How can I create a class with a member named "channel" with a method naed Nofault? The content of NoFault will be implemented by me.

Comment: In that case I'll provide an answer shortly

Comment: My answer is a bit of a read, but since you seem to be a complete beginner, I think it will be worth your time to process the whole thing. Please don't forget to select it if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It definitely worth the time. I will implement the whole thing and let you know. It is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, your actual question is pretty general, and you should try to be more specific in the future. On the other hand, it is often difficult for a beginner to know where to start, so I will provide you with some design tips that should help you get through this challenge.

**No nested classes**

Nested classes are pretty much useless in Python. Perfectly legal, but pointless. They do not give you magical access to the containing class, and are not present in any of the instances (as they might be in Java). All that nesting does is to make the namespace more complex.

The first thing I would do is to move `Channel` out of `FaultInsertionBoard`. A simple unindent will suffice. I will show you how to use it a bit further down.

**Naming convention**

Another thing to keep in mind is Python naming convention. While not a requirement, it is common to capitalize only class names, while everything else is lowercase with underscores between words (instead of camelCase).

It is also conventional *not* to put spaces around the `=` in the definition of a default value for a function parameter.

I will follow these conventions throughout this answer.

**Inheritance vs containment**

You should probably use inheritance rather than containment for `FaultInsertionBoard`:

```
class FaultInsertionBoard(Arduino):
    pass
```

This will make `FaultInsertionBoard` have all the methods and attributes of `Arduino`. You can now do `fault_board.method()` instead of `fault_board.board.method()`, where `method` is some method of the `Arduino` class.

You will probably need to define some additional initialization steps, like setting a default value for the `com_port`, and later setting up the channels. You can define your own version of `__init__` and call the parent class's implementation whenever you want:

```
class FaultInsertionBoard(Arduino):
    def __init__(self, com_port='COM3'):
        super().__init__(com_port)
```

If you use Python 2.x, use `super(FaultInsertionBoard, self).__init__`.

**Adding channels**

To be able to actually access channel instances, you need to define some data structure to hold them, and initialize some channels up front. The data structure can be accessible directly as an attribute, or through a method that does some additional checking of the parameters.

As I mentioned earlier, nesting the `Channel` class will not move you in this direction at all. In fact, since your `Channel` class probably needs access to its parent board, we will add a new initialization parameter to its constructor:

```
class Channel:
    def __init__(self, channel_id, parent):
        self.id = channel_id
        self.parent = parent
```

You have a couple of options available to you. The simplest is to initialize a sequence of `Channel`s in `FaultInsertionBoard`, which you can access via `[]` rather than `()`:

```
class FaultInsertionBoard(Arduino):
    def __init__(self, com_port='COM3'):
        super().__init__(com_port)
        self.channels = []
        self.channels.append(Channel(0, self))
        self.channels.append(Channel(1, self))
        ...
```

Now `main` will look like this:

```
def main():
    fault_board = FaultInsertionBoard('COM3')
    v_out_sensor = fault_board.channels[0]  
    i_out_sensor = fault_board.channel[1]
    v_out_sensor.no_fault()
    v_out_sensor.short_to_ground()
    i_out_sensor.no_fault()
    i_out_sensor.short_to_ground()
```

If you absolutely want to use parentheses to access the channels as `channel(0)`, etc., you can define a method in `FaultInsertionBoard`. Keeping the `__init__` method the same, you can add another method:

```
def channel(self, index):
    # Check index if you want to, possibly raise an error if invalid
    return self.channels[index]
```

In this case `main` will look like this:

```
def main():
    fault_board = FaultInsertionBoard('COM3')
    v_out_sensor = fault_board.channel(0)  
    i_out_sensor = fault_board.channel(1)
    v_out_sensor.no_fault()
    v_out_sensor.short_to_ground()
    i_out_sensor.no_fault()
    i_out_sensor.short_to_ground()
```

The first method has the advantage of allowing you direct access to the sequence of `Channel` objects. Since you are applying the same operation to the channels, you can iterate over all of them for an even simpler interface:

```
def main():
    fault_board = FaultInsertionBoard('COM3')
    for channel in fault_board.channels:
        channel.no_fault()
        channel.short_to_ground()
```

**Convenience methods**

It appears that you use the operation `x.no_fault(); x.short_to_ground()` multiple times in your code. It is often helpful to create what is called a convenience method in that case. You could add the following to `Channel`:

```
def reset(self):
    self.no_fault()
    self.short_to_ground()
```

And `main` could then look like this:

```
def main():
    fault_board = FaultInsertionBoard('COM3')
    for channel in fault_board.channels:
        channel.reset()
```